# Deciphering JSON from AcousticBrainz

Tags: java, json

I stumbled upon AcousticBrainz and I am trying to get the data from their database. They give me the API (acousticbrainz.org/api). Unfortunatley I am new to JSON and 
I am not exactly sure how to get the info. I am trying to get the info from 
http://acousticbrainz.org/8e160042-b451-4f96-b59a-d06831d2ae05/high-level

I know that there are only two JSON Objects. "highlevel" and "metadata"

This is how they present their info
http://acousticbrainz.org/8e160042-b451-4f96-b59a-d06831d2ae05

I am coding in Java and this is what I have

```
String URL = "http://acousticbrainz.org/8e160042-b451-4f96-b59a-d06831d2ae05/high-level";
String Json = IOUtils.toString(new URL(URL));
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(Json);
JSONObject jom = new JSONObject(jo.get("metadata"));

System.out.println(jo.names());
System.out.println(jom.names());
System.out.println(jo.get("metadata"));
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?? is it making a call to the URL and get the json data or parsing the json data??

Comment: parsing the data. I just get a bunch of keys and their values with a lot of curly braces. it looks like a bunch of objects inside objects inside objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to make API call and get the json data you can use the following code:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder().setScheme("http")
        .setHost("acousticbrainz.org")
        .setPath("/8e160042-b451-4f96-b59a-d06831d2ae05/high-level");

HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new HttpGet(builder.build());

HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(httpUriRequest);

String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

And if you want to parse the json data and use it you can check the below sample code:

```
JSONObject metaDataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("metadata");

String md5EncodedValue = metaDataObject.getJSONObject("audio_properties")
        .getString("md5_encoded");

System.out.println(md5EncodedValue);
```

if you are using maven then add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20131018</version>
</dependency>
```

or use [this link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20131018/json-20131018.jar) to download the jar

Comment: So that is exactly what I was looking for thank you. A few questions though. 1) why use the ApacheHTTPClient Library, isn't what I had the same thing? 2) what exactly would you consider the "audio_properties key... A member of the metadata object? and the "md5_encoded" key...?

Comment: **audio_properties** key is holding a json object and with in that **md5_encoded** is a property. Instead of holding object i'm chaining the call to load the property of that object its like **object.getObject.getProperty**

Comment: What library does JSONObject come from ?